# Which kernel should I update to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new Lenovo IdeaPad 130 and it turned out that the Linux kernel 4.18 didn't support my touchpad (ELAN 0620), but it is supported in other kernels (4.19 and above). So now I'm going to upgrade my kernel using UKUU to one that supports my hardware but I don't know which one to choose as I'm quite new to this.

Are there any factors that should be considered when upgrading the kernel, or is newer better?

Comment: If you fully-upgrade your Ubuntu 18.04, you'll find yourself on the 5.0 kernel, as 4.15 is the default kernel for Ubuntu 18.04, but 4.18 was used for awhile if you had HWE enabled (or installed with 18.04.2 or higher, but it's now 5.0).   Upgrade your system using normal means (`sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't install a mainline kernel from UKUU. It won't get updates and is not officially supported. UKUU kernels are for testing purposes, or when there is no Ubuntu kernel with a specific feature or fix.

You can install an Ubuntu HWE kernel using:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

That will be kernel 5.0.

If you initially installed 18.04.2 instead of 18.04, you will have it already.

Answer (score 2):

If you fully-upgrade your Ubuntu 18.04, you'll find yourself on the 5.0 kernel, as 4.15 is the default kernel for Ubuntu 18.04, but 4.18 was used for awhile if you had HWE enabled (or installed with 18.04.2 or higher, but it's now 5.0).

Upgrade your system using normal means (`sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade`) and 4.18 will auto-upgrade to 5.0  (assuming you didn't manually add the 4.18 kernel, it was default for an un-upgraded 18.04.2 install; 18.04.2 and later installs have HWE enabled)

Comment: Your investigation is correct.